# How can i change position of upload button and preview thumbnail using react-fine-uploader

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using react-fine-uploader to upload files. All are working fine but i want to change position upload button and preview thumbnails like button should be in bottom of page and thumbnail should be in somewhere middle of the body .

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import FileInput from 'react-fine-uploader/file-input' 
import FineUploaderTraditional from 'fine-uploader-wrappers' 
const uploader = new FineUploaderTraditional({ options: { request: { endpoint: 'my/upload/endpoint' } } }) 
const fileInput = ( <FileInput multiple accept='image/*' uploader={ uploader }> <span class="icon ion-upload">Choose Files</span> </FileInput> )
ReactDOM.render( fileInput, document.getElementById('content') )
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import FileInput from 'react-fine-uploader/file-input'
import FineUploaderTraditional from 'fine-uploader-wrappers'

const uploader = new FineUploaderTraditional({
   options: {
      request: {
         endpoint: 'my/upload/endpoint'
      }
   }
})

const fileInput = (
   <FileInput multiple accept='image/*' uploader={ uploader }>
      <span class="icon ion-upload">Choose Files</span>
   </FileInput>
)

ReactDOM.render(
    fileInput,
    document.getElementById('content')
)